# Combine date and time into one new column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two columns named date and time respectively. Both of them have datatype nvarchar as they were imported from ms excel. I want to combine the column into a new column named datetime. I managed to get the result as I wanted by using:

```
SELECT date + ' ' + time as datetime
FROM column1
```

But I can't insert them into the new column.

Comment: But I can't insert them into the new column ? Can you describe it litle bit more, Do you want to update 3th column i table If yes whic type of data hold that column, Or you want to select results ?

Answer (score 1):

Does the new column already exist? If it doesn't then you need to create it:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD [DateTime] DateTime2(0) NULL;
```

Then you go and "insert":

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET [DateTime] = CONVERT(DateTime2(0), (date + ' ' + time))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
cast(cast(cast(date  as date) as varchar(30))+' '+time  as datetime)
from column1
```

Here is sample

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d8009/2

Comment: but this will just view the result. how to insert the result into a new column?

Comment: `INSERT INTO my_table (field, list) SELECT field,list FROM what_ever;`